# Getting Again the Message To Allow or Not the User Location into the iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I am testing with iPhone simulator and I want to get the message to allow or not the user location. My problem is that I have clicked once (to test it) the no button with the Do not show this message again checked. How can I get it again?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: No one knows if I can get again this message into the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have the answer to this problem. Into the iOS Simulator, you have to click under the "iOS Simulator" window menu and to choose the "Reset content and settings" options.